# OpenLayers v3.10.1 problem getting vector layer features unless layer visibility initially set to true

Tags: openlayers

This is driving me crazy because I had it working with an earlier version: I'm trying to use the feature extents of a hidden (off) layer to set my zoom-to code for a given feature, but the only way I can get it to work now is to initially load the layer with visibility 'true':

```
areas_extents_src = new ol.source.Vector({
            crossOrigin : 'anonymous',
            projection : 'EPSG:3857',
            format : new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            url : wfsURL + 'jbwq:sample-envelope-200m&outputFormat=json'
});

sampling_areas_extents = new ol.layer.Vector({
            title : 'Sampling Area Boundaries',
            name : 'sampling_areas_extents',
            source : areas_extents_src,
            visible : true,
            style : extentsOn
});// end SAE wfs layer
```

then do this:

```
sampling_areas_extents.once('postcompose', function(event){
    map.render();
    sampling_areas_extents.setVisible(false);
});
```

which just seems wrong! But no amount of hacking - turning the layer on *before* the rest of the zoom function, trying to clear/reload source, loading the layer with a hidden style, etc., will accomplish what I need. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: What is your vector layer and source config?

Comment: edited to show source/layer config.

Comment: Did you overcome this one?

Comment: @Jonatas - No, I'm stuck using what I posted above, which works fine, but I regard it as an ugly hack! It seems clear that the layer has been fetched even if not visible, I can see the data in the DOM, but unless/until its visibility is set to true, that data isn't accessible to the OL library functions.

Comment: Hi @AnnieG, I think you could start with a custom loader, so you'll have more control when the source is ready. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/ayewaz87/). I'm not sure what you're trying to do but let's build the solution together.

Comment: Thanks @Jonatas! I think it can work with the custom loader idea - but construction continues, so will have to circle back after solving my next problem - which may appear here shortly! Should/can I mark this solved, or should I wait until I actually test it?

Comment: Well, there isn't yet an answer, is it solved? You could post it and mark as correct.